# What is getTenant in servoy implementing security example?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I am new to Servoy platform 
i am trying to create custom login solution where user can login and use application. I am using below code as a reference.Here i am unable to understand the meaning of getTenant.

```
function login(){

errorMessage = null;

if(!userName){
    errorMessage = 'Please specify a user name';
    return false;
}
if(!password){
    errorMessage = 'Please specify a password';
    return false;
}

var tenantID = security.authenticate("myAuthenticator","getTenant",[userName]);
if(tenantID){
    if(security.authenticate("myAuthenticator","loginUser",[userName,password])){
        return true;
    } else {
        errorMessage = "No tenant found. Please check your password";
    }
}
errorMessage = 'Login Failed';
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "getTenant" and "loginUser" are custom methods in the authenticator solution which both serve different purposes. The first method seems to be retrieving the tenant ID based on the username. If successful it will try to login by using the second method. To actually login the user, you would need to call "security.login" from within the authenticator solution.

I assume you are getting this code from here: https://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Implementing+Security? The last example shows how to actually login inside the authenticator solution.

Comment: Thank you. I get it